# How to encrypt and Insert data in Resource Controllers in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, encryption, resources

In my laravel web application, 
I am inserting data through the resource controller .
 it's working suessfully.
but what I want to do is encrypt the data and insert into db.
How can I do that? 
 I tried laravel encryption. but it's not working
I'm using the below code to insert the data into db.

```
 $data_array=encrypt($request->all());
 $data=$this->Ipr_type->create($data_array)->id;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encrypt each column separately:

```
$this->Ipr_type->create([
    'some_column1' => encrypt($request->column1),
    'some_column2' => encrypt($request->column2),
]);
```

Comment: How can I decrypt and return last inserted Id?

Comment: @palika you don't need to decrypt it. Just do `$this->Ipr_type->create([....])->id`

Answer (score 1):

You're encrypting the entire array into one value, instead you need to be encrypting each value within `$request->all()`:

```
$data = array_walk($request->all(), function (&$a, $b) { $a = encrypt($b); });
$encryptedData = $this->Ipr_type->create($data);
```